# Results are not populating after fetching from API using React

Tags: reactjs

I am working with some examples to fetch the data from an API using `fetch`. But, it is returning nothing in view. What i am doing wrong? Why it is not populating? Here is a [link to the code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-26wuuh).

Application code here:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import axios from 'axios';
import './style.css';

const url='https://10degrees.uk/wp-json/wp/v2/posts';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      searchInput: 'tirur',
      avatarDatas: []
    };
    this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchData(url);
  }

  fetchData = (apiToFetch)=>{
     fetch(apiToFetch)
     .then(result=>result.json())
     .then(avatarData=>{
       this.setState({
         avatarDatas : avatarData
       })
     })
     .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.avatarDatas)
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello name={this.state.name} />
        <p>
        {this.state.avatarDatas.map(item=>{
          <div>{item}</div>
        })}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fetching data from the remote URL correctly. However, you're using the `map` function in your `render` method wrong. You have:

```
{this.state.avatarDatas.map(item=>{
  <div>{item}</div>
})}
```

This does indeed map through all the entries in `avatarDatas`, but the function the callback you've provided the `map` isn't returning anything. You've written a function block with a JSX statement in it, and no return statement. What you should have written is:

```
{this.state.avatarDatas.map(item=>{
  return (<div>{item}</div>);
})}
```

or even this, where there isn't an actual function block but just a return value:

```
{this.state.avatarDatas.map(item=>
  <div>{item}</div>
)}
```

At this point, the `avatarDatas` still won't be listed, because the JSX in your `map` callback is trying to have `item` rendered. `item` is an object, and React won't know how to convert it to a string. Rather do this:

```
{this.state.avatarDatas.map(item=>
  <div>{item.title.rendered}</div>
)}
```

(Or any other of the many fields that each `avatarData` has.)

Finally, React may still issue a warning, saying that each item in a list must have a unique key. Whenever you use `map` to create a number of elements, React expects you to give a unique identifier to each element, which it will use to identify that element when it needs to update your list during rerendering. That means that you should do this:

```
{this.state.avatarDatas.map((item, index) =>
  <div key={index}>{item.title.rendered}</div>
)}
```

Now, your `map` callback assigns an index to each `<div>` and all is well with the world.